# What all should an android application contain to get Flurry Analytics?

Tags: android, flurry

I have successfully integrated the Flurry jar into my Android application and I am able to use the methods FlurryAgent.onStartSession and FlurryAgent.onEndSession.

But I am not getting any statistics of my application in the Flurry analytics?

In my application I have only one screen and I am redirecting it to Google.com. Would this capture any analytics?

If not let me know what all should an application contain so that I can capture all the Flurry analytics like Sessions, Median Session Length and New users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics are not updated immediately. It usually takes a couple of hours until a result is visible in Flurry analytics.